# How can I authenticate on UCM from my application?

Tags: web-services, authentication, ldap, authorization, oracle-ucm

I need to call UCM (Oracle WebCenter Content) web services, that requires authentication.
My application uses the same users, that used by UCM (I am using LDAP), but I dont know theirs passwords (they are stored in LDAP in encrypted state), so I couldn't use theirs credentials for authentication on UCM.
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give version of UCM or what app server you are running on. Current production of Oracle UCM, now called WebCenterContent, 11.1.1.8, runs inside the App Server's domain. I suggest you look at how to call a web service in app server that will use its authentication provider. UCM does not do its own authentication. It is done by the app server. 
Reading about web service security here might [help](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2003/jw-0321-wssecurity.html?page=2)